# Creating an update trigger that uses data from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

Okay, so I have made the changes that i know how to make but I am still stuck at how to bring the accessory table in. For those first time here, I'm trying to create a trigger that checks that prices are appropriately changed. However, one of the columns I need comes from another table and I'm not quite sure how to declare that variable. This is my current attempt.

The ACCESSORY table is a child of the PRODUCT table being connected with ProductCode and has only 1 other column called Class which stands for classification. The trigger i created is currently for the PRODUCT table as that is where all the prices are recorded

```
CREATE TRIGGER PriceCheck1
ON PRODUCT
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @ProductCode        AS  Char(6),
        @ProductName        AS  VarChar(50),
        @StockLevel         AS  Int,
        @OldPrice           AS  float, @NewPrice AS float,
        @ProductType        AS  VarChar(9)
        --@Class                AS VarChar(20)
/*SELECT i.ProductCode, i.ProductName, i.ProductStockLevel, i.ProductPrice, i.ProductType, a.Class
INTO #TempTable
FROM inserted i JOIN ACCESSORY a ON i.ProductCode = a.ProductCode*/


SELECT  @ProductCode = ProductCode, @ProductName = ProductName,
        @StockLevel = ProductStockLevel, @NewPrice = ProductPrice,
        @ProductType = ProductType --@Class = Class
FROM    inserted;--FROM    #TempTable

SELECT  @ProductCode = ProductCode, @ProductName = ProductName,
        @StockLevel = ProductStockLevel, @OldPrice = ProductPrice,
        @ProductType = ProductType
FROM    deleted;

IF UPDATE(ProductPrice)
BEGIN
    IF (@ProductType = 'Food Item' AND @NewPrice > 200)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('The price of food item cannot exceed $200.', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
    ELSE IF (@ProductType = 'Accessory' AND @NewPrice < 50)--AND @Class = 'Bed and Bedding'
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('The price of any accessory with a classification that includes the word bed cannot be less than $50.', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
    ELSE
        print 'Price of Product Code ' + @ProductCode + ' has been changed from $' + Cast(@OldPrice AS nVarChar(10)) + ' to $' + Cast(@NewPrice AS nVarChar(10)) + '.'
END
END
```

The Areas that i commented out are the codes i tried. The trigger works fine without the commented out areas but now when i tried to bring the accessory table in, the trigger doesn't even fire when i update the table.

Comment: You reference a variable called `@Class` without ever declaring it?

Comment: In future please post the exact errors... normally they tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: What does that syntax error exactly say ? (position, line, etc. ...)

Comment: I'm not so sure how do i declare a variable that belongs to another table, i have edited the errors in the question

Comment: Its about the logic of it, where would `@Class` come from? We don't know - its your database :) and `@Class` can only hold one value? Is that what you want? Or do you need multiple values a normal set based operation?

Comment: @Class comes from the ACCESSORY table which is a child of the PRODUCT table being connected with ProductCode as the FK. The trigger i created is currently for the PRODUCT table as that is where all the prices are recorded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back. Start over! This is the wrong general approach. First, stop blindly applying a pattern. Using  to create a temp table and then referencing that temp table serves no useful purpose here.

Next, you assume a single row is affected. That is a very common mistake and has been discussed many, many times. Go learn from past discussions - something you should be doing for every question or problem you might have.

When you consider that multiple rows can be affected, you will realize that your attempt to provide a "beautiful" error message is impossible. So just don't do that. In fact, don't attempt that regardless of the number of rows. The client application should render the error as needed to the user. Let it choose the words and language and format any needed values according to the user's preferences.

Next, you are developing lazy coding habits. This will only create more work over time. Your second-to-last statement inserts a row into Product. ALWAYS use a column list in an insert statement.

Next, returning to that next-to-last statement. Why are you inserting a row into the table on which this trigger is defined. That is most likely an error. Maybe you intended to update the updated rows? Maybe you actually have a separate audit table? Questions like these are best answered by including a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Next, let's look at one of your statements. You have:

```
SELECT @ProductCode = 'Code', @ProductName = 'Name',
    @ProductStockLevel = 'Stock Level', @OldPrice = 'Price',
    @ProductType = 'Type'
    FROM #TempTable
```

What do you think this does? It appears you tried to assign values to a number of variables - values that should come from a row in the table. But does it? Nope - it simply assigns (or tries to - this will generate runtime errors) the literals you have used.

So finally something that might work. I say "might" because you may change your direction when you see this in action. Below is a best guess (with pseudo code) that looks for just one of the problem conditions. It can be expanded by adding logic to the case expression. I leave that to you.

```
if exists (select * from inserted as ins 
   inner join deleted as del 
      on ins.<ID columns?> = del.<ID columns?> 
   inner join dbo.ACCESSORY as acc 
      on ins.ProductCode  = acc.ProductCode 
   where (case when acc.Type = 'Food Item' and ins.price > 200 then 1 else 0 end) = 1)
begin 
    throw error
end;
```

Notice that I joined the inserted and deleted tables. Your logic does actually need it but I included it simply to show how it is done - for example, if you wanted to restrict the "size" of the change. If you don't need to refer to the prior values for each row it can be removed. If you actually needed to update some "audit" column in the Product table for every changed value, you would use the same join logic to populate this column.

One final comment. You have:

```
RAISERROR ('The price of any accessory with a classification that includes the word bed cannot be less than $50.')
```

Your error messages should not lie or mislead. That message does not accurately describe the logic you tried to use.

Comment: Okay I edited my code and made quite abit of changes. I see where i was wrong. Initially i was just following a youtube video. However, I still have problems joining the Accessory table in

Answer (score 0):

You're not declaring @Class, and you're not assigning it a value.
What are you expecting @Class to be, and how is it getting assigned a value?

edit: I don't think you even need to do this. Confirm that there is only a 1-1 relationship between Product and Accessory? In which case you don't need the where clause.

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempTable
FROM PRODUCT p JOIN ACCESSORY a ON p.ProductCode = a.ProductCode
```

And then Class will be in that temp table, and you can assign it as required the same as you have already done for the other values.

Comment: How do i declare @Class if its a column from another table? I think that's the biggest problem i'm facing

Comment: @Aaron Actually this is the smallest problem you are facing. See SMor answer for bigger problems.